# Revert version of unpublished Node.js package

Tags: npm

I have a package which I released on NPM and it's currently at version `1.0.1`.

I have made some changes locally, and wanted to publish them.
I entered `npm version 1.0.3` and then felt stupid, because I wanted to type `npm version 1.0.2`.

*How can I restore this mistake?*

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A colleague just suggested to reset my repository to the remote repository and try again, it worked.

I first used the following commands to reset my repository's master branch (as if it's a clean clone):

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Also delete the tags from local and remote
`git tag -d 1.0.2` Remove from local repo
`git push --delete origin 1.0.2` remove from remote repo

Then I simply added the version:

```
npm version 1.0.2
```

Comment: For anyone else that finds this, you also need to make sure to delete the tag created. `git tag -d v1.0.3`

Comment: If you haven't published to npm yet, you can edit the version in the package.json
Change `"version": "1.0.0"` to `"version": "0.0.0",` or whatever your usecase may be.