# How to rollback "npm version minor" - updated minor instead of "patch"

Tags: npm, npm-version

I made a silly mistake, I wanted to update the version of my npm library by X.X.1 - basically I should have used `npm version patch` but because I am stupid I ran `npm version minor`. So my library version is 0.3.0 instead of 0.2.1. How do I undo the minor update so I can apply the patch?

I would rather do this through the terminal / command line as it would also update my lock file too.

I am currently looking through the docs but you often get a straight answer here and I find your comments most useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After searching I just did a soft reset `$ git reset --soft HEAD~1` and then applied the correct update command

Comment: Unfortunately a soft reset would leave the tag.
A more complete answer has been given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583667/revert-version-of-unpublished-node-js-package

You have to hard reset and delete the tag.